# Lua Scrape Website for single line of text

Tags: http, web, lua

I have a website www.example.com that holds one line of text such as "hello world". Is there any built in method in LUA that would let me grab that? If not, is there a module? I saw harvester, but I couldn't find much of any documentation on it. Sorry. I'm a huge noob to this LUA stuff.

Comment: `text = io.popen'wget -qO - www.example.com':read'*a'`

Answer (score 1):

There are not built-in facilities for this in Lua. Try [LuaSocket](http://luasocket.luaforge.net/).